# issue with javascript for loop not executing every time

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm using this JavaScript code for alert count in an array of pages.

urls is an array of page names, and count is the count value.

I want to alert the count value in each pages of the array urls.

But the for loop is not executing all time. I don't know what happens... Any body please help me to find out the mistake..

Am using `echo $_POST['suggest'];` in the array of pages. But i want to use JavaScript code for receiving the value of suggest and alert it. How to receive the value using JavaScript?

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var count = document.getElementById('display_visitor_number').innerHTML; //count
            var urls = document.getElementById('display_visitor_urls').innerHTML; //array of page names
            var myarr = urls.split(",");

            for (var i=1;i<myarr.length;i++)
            { 
                $.post(myarr[i],{suggest:count}, function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                });
            }


        });
    </script>
```

Comment: array index are 0-based, so you should start with `for(var i=0 ...)`

Comment: Try `$.post(myarr[i+1]` and  in the condition change `i<=myarr.length`
this will fix your issue

Comment: I tried this.. but if i start with 0 then loop is executed but whole contents of the page is alerted while executing

Comment: can you put up the value contained in urls?

Comment: The web server sends back the page you requested as `data`, so this is expected.

Comment: ya..I have an option to add page names, and save these names in to a text file

Comment: Why would you link in jQuery, but then use `document.getElementById`?

Answer (score 0):

if the string urls starts with , before you split it will have an empty string as first value (this will cause jquery to make an ajax call for the current page) you may want to check for that and start with 0

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var count = document.getElementById('display_visitor_number').innerHTML; //count
            var urls = document.getElementById('display_visitor_urls').innerHTML; //array of page names
            var myarr = urls.split(",");

            for (var i=0;i<myarr.length;i++)
            { 
                if(myarr[i] !== '')$.post(myarr[i],{suggest:count}, function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                });
            }


        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `split` function you'd better try RegExp and match all non-space character sequences. replace

```
var myarr = urls.split(",");
```

with

```
var myarr = urls.match(/[^ ,]+/g)
```

and you should start you `for` loop with `var i=0` then.